# Like Button In Django Ajax

Tags: ajax, django, python-2.7

my like button is working fine without ajax with page reloading but it is having problem when done by implementing ajax. the like and unlike is happening in the backend (like is created and deleted in database on ajax Post request), but the like count,like,unlike button does not change in response on ajax post request, until the page is reloaded. Need Help

here is the post model and like model for posting image and liking it in models.py

```
class PostModel(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel)
 image = models.FileField(upload_to='user_images')
 image_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 caption = models.CharField(max_length=240)
 created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
 has_liked = False

 @property
 def like_count(self):
 return len(LikeModel.objects.filter(post=self))

 class LikeModel(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel)
  post = models.ForeignKey(PostModel)
  created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

url for liking in urls.py

```
    url(r'^like/', like_view),
```

views.py

```
 def like_view(request):
    user = check_validation(request)
    if user and request.method == 'POST':
       form = LikeForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           #post_id = form.cleaned_data.get('post').id
           post_id=request.POST['post']

           existing_like = LikeModel.objects.filter(post_id=post_id, user=user).first()

           if not existing_like:
                LikeModel.objects.create(post_id=post_id, user=user)
           else:
                existing_like.delete()

        return redirect('/feed/')

    else:
        return redirect('/login/')
```

template.html

```
    {% for post in posts %}
    <form id="like_form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="post" id="post_id"value="{{ post.id }}">
      {% if post.has_liked %}
      <button class="btn btn-link unlike"type="submit"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"style="color:#ed4956;"></i></button>
      {% else %}
      <button class="btn btn-link like"type="submit"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"style=color:#333333;"></i></button>
      {% endif %}

     </form>
    {% endfor %}
```

Javascript code

```
      <script>

      $(document).on('submit','#like_form',function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'/like/',
      data:{
      post:$('#post_id').val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()

      },
      success:function (response) {
        console.log("liked");
    }

    });

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: You don't want your like to view redirect... You want it to return a response that's hopefully successful, and then your javascript success function toggles the elements on the page...

Comment: please tell me how can I do that

Comment: Well, `return HttpResponse()` at the end of checking your form is valid is a crude method of indicating a successful response (but you may want to return a `JsonResponse` with info of whether it was newly liked or unliked) - the rest is whatever javascript/jquery you need to write to update the page accordingly

Comment: You need to do something in your Ajax `success` function to actually change what's on the page.

Comment: ya i was done with it , thanks hor the help